# MySQL optimise triple left join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to make a query that gets columns from various tables - 5 tables in total. I am happy to be getting the gist of left joins, and getting the results I need, the only problem is the speed. I am a bit lost on indexes/keys, possibly because my case is atypical to all the examples I am reading online. The "unique" id across my tables is not a primary key in all of tables and cant be because that id can have several rows in the table (historical/audit purposes). The id is also in different formats across a few tables (##/### and ##-###) so the function to match them might be causing the big slow up. It may be easier to paste my code so far (only 3 tables - not doing all of them until I can conquer 3 first!), and someone can hopefully suggest how to improve with indexes and keys.

```
SELECT dc.URN,dc.GuideName,dc.GuideStreet,ss.categorycalc,pm.initiatedate
FROM dc
LEFT JOIN pm
ON dc.URN = pm.URN
LEFT JOIN ss
ON dc.URN = replace(ss.URN,"/","-")
WHERE dc.GuidePCode LIKE 'WA9%'
ORDER BY pm.Status ASC;
```

I would appreciate less advice to just start the database all over and 'do it properly' etc. - there are a lot of programs already coded to insert data to certain tables in certain ways. So it is quite impractical to change the structure of the unique id, and the way it is being written to certain tables. I just need to focus on pulling off this report of the data that I have already got. The "WA9" part will change depending on what the user wants to search for.

Comment: What is the [query execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) of that query?  Start there or post the results and show your `CREATE TABLE` syntax and indexes for each table.  There isn't enough information in the question to go on.

Answer (score 2):

First I would do an EXPLAIN. Check the MySQL manual for proper usage, but it's basically:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT dc.URN,dc.GuideName,dc.GuideStreet,ss.categorycalc,pm.initiatedate 
FROM dc 
LEFT JOIN pm ON dc.URN = pm.URN 
LEFT JOIN ss ON dc.URN = replace(ss.URN,"/","-") 
WHERE dc.GuidePCode LIKE 'WA9%' 
ORDER BY pm.Status ASC;
```

Look at the "key" column. If it is empty on a row for a table, then you probably need indexes on those fields. I would suggest you add the following if you don't already have it:
(btw, run this on a testing environment first)

```
ALTER TABLE dc ADD INDEX URNIdx (URN);
ALTER TABLE pm ADD INDEX URNIdx (URN);
ALTER TABLE dc ADD INDEX GuidePCodeIdx (GuidePCode);
```

I would say to try adding an index to the table ss, but I think it's better to create a new column called URNdashed to ss with the same definiton as URN. Then run this UPDATE:

```
UPDATE ss SET URNdashed = replace(ss.URN, "/", "-");
```

Also add an index to URNdashed:

```
ALTER TABLE ss ADD INDEX URNdashedIdx (URNdashed);
```

THEN change your:

```
ON dc.URN = replace(ss.URN,"/","-") 
to 
ON dc.URN = URNdashed
```

See if that helps. I hope I steared you in the correct direction!

Comment: pretty awesome for a first post!

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. I have since discovered that the ss table is myisam and the   rest are innodb though, which I am going to guess is a factor. How can I set up a trigger so that each time a new row is inserted to ss it copies the ##-### version of the urns to the new column? Would it be better to set up a new innodb table just for urns and category calc

Comment: Different table types shouldn't be an issue with JOINs....as long as EXPLAIN shows the indexes are being used, you should be ok.  I do them all the time. They might have to be the same type and length, so if one is defined as _TINYINT(1)_ the other should be too. Make sure if you are decreasing the length, you aren't truncating the column, so do a `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(pm.URN)) FROM pm` I don't have time at the moment to explain a trigger, but that is a possible solution besides doing it in your application. I'd suggest Googling **MySQL trigger examples** for now.